# Cyclomatic complexity difference between switch/cases and in_array

Tags: php, cyclomatic-complexity, phpmd

**Scenario**

I need to check if my `$type_id` variable is one of a certain set of IDs.

For no reason other than readability, I went with

```
switch($type_id) {
    case Type::SOME_TYPE:
    case Type::SOME_OTHER_TYPE:
    ...
        //do stuff
```

where most of them cascade down to a common case.

But this increases the cyclomatic complexity to the point where PHPMD starts whining.

So I figured, let's just use `in_array()` instead.

```
if (in_array($type_id, [
    Type::SOME_TYPE,
    TYPE::SOME_OTHER_TYPE,
    ...
    ])) {
    //do stuff
}
```

**Question**

At this point PHPMD stops complaining, but isn't the cyclomatic complexity still there, just hidden behind the `in_array()` function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. But the PHPMD rule is for CC inside a single method/function. It doesn't apply the CC across the entire callgraph. In general, you can solve any PHPMD CC warning by extracting a branch into it's own method.

On a side note: consider to [replace the conditional with polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: Does that mean that CC is only considered "mess" due to unreadability?

Comment: @Alec No, it doesn't necessarily mean hard to read. Its more about being able to grasp or reason about a method/function. If there are many possible branches through a piece of code, it gets more difficult to say for this input x, the output will be y. This in turn has direct implications for the number of unit-tests you will need to cover the function. The Wikipedia article is quite thorough: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity